# r run hardcoded regression on subset of data

Tags: r, linear-regression

If this is my dataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
           ID = 1:6,
           Group = c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Blue"),
           X = c(10, 11, 11, 12, 9, 13))
```

| ID | Group | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | 10 |
| 2 | Red | 11 |
| 3 | Blue | 11 |
| 4 | Red | 12 |
| 5 | Blue | 9 |
| 6 | Blue | 13 |

I have two linear regression equations:

```
 (Eq. 1) Y ~ 34    + 0.35 * X [ where Group == "Red" ]
 (Eq. 2) Y ~ 33.67 + 0.37 * X [ where Group == "Blue"]
```

How do I predict Y from this regression question using my dataset?

Comment: Could you add to your question what you tried and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, I have not tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidyverse solution would be

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% mutate(Y = ifelse(Group == "Red", 34    + 0.35 * X, 33.67 + 0.37 * X ))
```

This assumes that you only have Group names of red and blue.

Comment: thanks mkpt, I am almost implemented a case_when solution.